# Missing java build path option in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap. 
When i tried to add third party java libs to android platform by right clicking on project in eclipse , there's no 'java build path' option for adding the java libs . 
I believe Eclipse do not recognize phonegap project as a java project , so the option is not visible. 
I wonder why most of the  online tutorial show such option available in phonegap + eclipse project ? Did i miss something ?
or is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Do you guys know how to  add jar libs manually to phonegap android project ?

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap should have this option, like any other project in Eclipse

If its grayed out then there may be an error within your project.

[image: This is the way to get to the build path]

Comment: There's no error that i can find . I was using eclipse luna with php and javascript plugin  to develope the phonegap app .   i  now open the same project with Eclipse mars with jdt .

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any more detailed errors? Have you tried changing the build path target? Maybe double check to make sure its referring to your JRE as well?

Comment: Mind telling me how to do that ?  I use Eclipse luna with JavaScript plugin for coding only and build the code with phonegap cli

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot, to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that those online tutorial doing it in eclipse + android environment and I'm doing it in Eclipse + multi-platform JavaScript environment.
I thought eclipse is smart enough to detect the android code within the phonegap project .